# take minimum between column value and constant global value

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe, minimum

I would like create new column for given dataframe where I calculate minimum between the column value and some global value (in this example 7). so my df has the columns `session` and `note` and my desired output column is `minValue` :

```
session     note     minValue
1       0.726841     0.726841
2       3.163402     3.163402  
3       2.844161     2.844161
4       NaN          NaN
```

I'm using the built in Python method `min` :

```
df['minValue']=min(7, df['note'])
```

and I have this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use [`np.minimum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html):

```
In [341]:
df['MinNote'] = np.minimum(1,df['note'])
df

Out[341]:
   session      note  minValue   MinNote
0        1  0.726841  0.726841  0.726841
1        2  3.163402  3.163402  1.000000
2        3  2.844161  2.844161  1.000000
3        4       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Also `min` doesn't understand array-like comparisons hence your error

Answer (score 42):

The preferred way to do this in `pandas` is to use the `Series.clip()` method.

In your example:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({'session': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                       'note': [0.726841, 3.163402, 2.844161, float('NaN')]})

df['minVaue'] = df['note'].clip(upper=1.)
df
```

Will return:

```
       note  session   minVaue
0  0.726841        1  0.726841
1  3.163402        2  1.000000
2  2.844161        3  1.000000
3       NaN        4       NaN
```

`numpy.minimum` will also work, but `.clip()` has some advantages:

- It is more readable
- You can apply simultaneously lower and upper bounds: `df['note'].clip(lower=0., upper=10.)`
- You can pipe it with other methods: `df['note'].abs().clip(upper=1.).round()`